# Probability: What is it called when you remove all items of a selected color?

Tags: terminology

This is possibly a very simple question. Suppose you have a container of colored balls. 3 blue, 4 purple, 2 yellow, and 1 red. We reach in and pick one out. It's purple. So we reach in and take all the purple balls out, before reaching in and selecting another ball.

Is this still called "Probability without Replacement"? Or is there a different terminology for it?

Is this an example of Truncation Selection? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncation_selection

Comment: "Without Replacement" generally means that before the next draw, you simply would not replace the purple ball from the first draw (given the starting configuration you could wind up with a purple on the second draw). As opposed to "With Replacement", where you put the first purple ball back before another draw.

Comment: @DreiCleaner So what is it called when you remove all balls of the same color before the next draw?

Comment: I have not heard of a special name for that.

Comment: @DreiCleaner I appreciate your time. Maybe someone knows. =)

Comment: @DreiCleaner Would you say this is an example of Truncation Selection?

Comment: I Googled that and it seems that is terminology used in genetics/breeding. It does seem loosely similar to what you are describing, but I don't think it is widely used in mathematics.

Comment: @DreiCleaner Wikipedia also lists a computer science example as well, which seems to match. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncation_selection